# Adding key value pair in a nested map dynamically

Tags: elixir

I have this map:

```
           %{
             "$include" => %{
                "hospitals" => %{
                   "$include" => %{"rooms" => %{"beds" => %{}}},
                   "$order" => %{"id" => "$asc"}
                },
               "doctors" => %{
                   "$order" => %{"id" => "$desc"}                      
                }
             }
          }
```

There is any number of $include statements nested inside $include. so it should be dynamic. The output should be.

```
           %{
             "$include" => %{
                "hospitals" => %{
                   "$include" => %{"rooms" => %{"beds" => %{"binding" => "last"}, "binding" => "last"}},
                   "$order" => %{"id" => "$asc"},
                   "binding" => "first"
                },
               "doctors" => %{
                   "$order" => %{"id" => "$desc"},
                   "binding" => "first"
                }
             }
          }
```

All the outer maps should include `binding => "first"` and all nested include should contain `"binding "=> "last"`.

I tried using `Enum.reduce` but I can't make it work

```
    Enum.reduce(params, %{}, fn {k, v}, acc ->
      v = Map.put(v, "binding", "last")
      Map.put(acc, k, if(is_map(v["$include"]), do: 
        add_bindings(v["$include"]), else: v))
    end)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check it out, may be of help -> https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate nasted map like this (I noticed that maps with **$** should not contain **binding** key):

```
def add_bindings(data, outer \\ true) when data |> is_map do
  data
  |> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn {key, value}, acc ->
    acc
    |> Map.put(
      key,
      if value |> is_map and String.first(key) != "$" do
        value
        |> Map.put("binding", if(outer, do: "first", else: "last"))
        |> add_bindings(false)
      else
        value |> add_bindings()
      end
    )
  end)
end

def add_bindings(data, _), do: data
```

Example data assigned to **data** variable:

```
data = %{
  "$include" => %{
    "hospitals" => %{
      "$include" => %{"rooms" => %{"beds" => %{}}},
      "$order" => %{"id" => "$asc"}
    },
    "doctors" => %{
      "$order" => %{"id" => "$desc"}
    }
  }
}
```

And **add_bindings** function call:

```
data |> add_bindings()
```